# How to:redirect localhost to my external IP address in Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, localhost

I'm using XAMPP to learn wordpress these days.I've established a simple site.After opening 80 port in my router,I can visit my site like this:

ExternalIP/wordpress

The problem is:I can **ONLY** open my index.php.I notice that the links in index.php all begin with "localhost/".I know I have to do something to modify it to my actual IP address,but I cannot figure out how to do it.What am I supposed to do?

Best regards.

Comment: You have to do it through Wordpress's settings page and change the blog URL to the IP address. The links themselves say `localhost`, which doesn't refer to your computer.

Comment: Do you mean,in wordpress's dashboard,change the default "http://localhost/wordpress" to "http://ExternalIP/wordpress"?

Comment: Thanks a lot!I was struggling with the Apache rewrite_module,never thought the problem could be fixed in such an easy way.:)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is easier to temporarily add your siteurl and home url to the config file, rather than updating the DB. That way when you go live you just remove the lines from your config.

Add the following lines to your `wp-config.php` file after `line 64` where it says `define('WPLANG', '');`

`define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://YOUR_LOCAL_IP');`
`define('WP_HOME', 'http://YOUR_LOCAL_IP');`

If you have WP in a sub-directory add that directory to the WP_SITEURL var only, for example:

`define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://YOUR_LOCAL_IP/wordpress');`
`define('WP_HOME', 'http://YOUR_LOCAL_IP');`

**Replace** `YOUR_LOCAL_IP` with your actual host machine IP, such as `http://192.168.0.1`.

If you are not developing locally, and only accessing remotely, you can use `YOUR_EXTERNAL_IP` in place of the local one.

Finally, navigate to WP Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks and click Save. This will reset WP to use your new value for links.

If you have any hardcoded links or images in Posts or Pages, you'll have to manually update the URLs for those.